# Como retornar uma lista em grupos separando por um determinado parametro?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by

Tenho uma formulário com os campos *Nome*, *Sobrenome* e *Sexo* e estou retomando uma lista usando [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/), porém preciso separar essa lista em grupos através do campo sexo,

```
grupo sexo = feminino 
grupo sexo = masculino
```

Como posso fazer isso, tem algum método que me ajude com isso ?

```
public Task<List<Formulario>> GetAll()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Method GetAll FormularioService");
    var formulario = _formularioRepository
                      .GetQueryable()
                      .Include(x => x.Status)
                      .ToList();
    return Task.FromResult(formulario);   
}
```

Comment: com Linq tem o `GroupBy`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

Comment: Você quer separar e fazer mais o que com esse agrupamento?

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma lista e agrupo com o GROUP BY, acredito que resolve o seu problema.

```
List<Formulario> _formularioRepository = new List<Formulario>();
List<List<Formulario>> _FormularioRepositories = new List<List<Formulario>>();

        _formularioRepository.Add(new Formulario { Nome = "Lucas",   Sobrenome= "", Sexo = "m" });
        _formularioRepository.Add(new Formulario { Nome = "Pedro",   Sobrenome= "", Sexo = "m" });
        _formularioRepository.Add(new Formulario { Nome = "Luis",    Sobrenome= "", Sexo = "m" });
        _formularioRepository.Add(new Formulario { Nome = "Luisa",   Sobrenome= "", Sexo = "f" });
        _formularioRepository.Add(new Formulario { Nome = "Debora",  Sobrenome= "", Sexo = "f" });
        _formularioRepository.Add(new Formulario { Nome = "Raquel",  Sobrenome= "", Sexo = "f" });

        var formulario_GroupBySexo = _formularioRepository.GroupBy(x => x.Sexo).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Assim como sugerido pelo Ricardo nos comentários você consegue usar a extensão **GROUP BY** do linq no C#

Um exemplo de como ficaria o novo código:

```
using System.Linq;

public Task<List<Formulario>> GetAll()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Method GetAll FormularioService");

        var formulario = _formularioRepository.GetQueryable()
                                               .Include(x => x.Status)
                                               .GroupBy(c => c.Sexo).ToList();

        return Task.FromResult(formulario);   
    }
```

Um artigo com mais exemplos de uso sobre o `linq` e `groupby`: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/groupby-in-linq/

Comment: a sua resposta não trará mais um dado de lista de ***Formulario***, a expressão ***Linq*** é condizendo, mas, o retorno muda pelo agrupamento proposto, e tem um outro fator, *qual o objetivo de agrupamento, vai contar, vai sumarizar de alguma forma?* ficou meio vago isso na pergunta e não é culpa sua.

Comment: Como o @novic comentou, falta ai na resposta alguns pontos... só adicionar o `GroupBy` não é suficiente, e mesmo assim, como já comentado não vai gerar um List de `Formulario`, é preciso melhorar.. me parece que apenas copiou o código e adicionou lá o `GroupBy`, tente dar mais detalhes na resposta para ela ficar mais clara, talvez possa fazer um pequeno exemplo de código no https://ideone.com/ ou no https://dotnetfiddle.net/ pra validar o código, ai melhor ainda

Comment: Eu tenho esse resultado e quero

Comment: @Josenilson se você tem esse resultado e quer a sua pergunta errada em contexto geral, não tem lógica usar um `GroupBy` para isso, mas, também eu não sei o objetivo central da pergunta, ficou vago

Comment: Basicamente o que quero é retornar o resultado da lista em grupos com base de um determinado parametro da lista e contar a quantidade desses grupos .